# Finding an equation satisfied by the negative Eigen values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I have a system 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda{y} =0$$
subject to $2y(0)+y'(0)=0$ and $y(1)=0$

Im trying to find the equation satisfied by negative eigenvalues. Heres what ive tried:

let $\lambda=-\alpha^2<0$

then,
$y(x)=Acosh(\alpha{x})+Bsinh(\alpha{x})$ and $y'(x)=A{\alpha}sinh(\alpha{x})+B{\alpha}coshh(\alpha{x})$

now using the constraints I get a transcendental equation

$tanh(\alpha)=\dfrac{\alpha}2$

And this is where I'm stuck. I've plotted a graph with $tanh(\alpha)$ and $\dfrac{\alpha}2$ and I can see that there are two intersections, one at zero and another positive one, but I don't really know if that helps me. Am I right in saying $\lambda_{\alpha}=-{\alpha^2}$ and eigen value? if so how do I find the corresponding eigenfunction?

Comment: I think you can't really say much more.

Comment: is there a corresponding eigenfunction?

Comment: of course there is

Comment: could you show me how to find it?

Comment: this is just the general solution where you include the constrains,

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, the constraints are $2y(0)+y'(0)=2A+B{\alpha}$ and $y(1)=Acosh({\alpha})+bsinh({\alpha})$ they give rise to the transcendental equation, how do I include them in the general solution?